# Flutter Firebase Google sign in with release version

Tags: firebase, flutter, release, google-signin, sha1

I am able to login to Google with my Flutter Firebase app in debug mode where I have signed the app with the debug key.

Now, my app just got released on Play Store and it is signed in with the release key. But, the app from Play Store - I am not able to sign in with Google. I have SHA1 entered in Firebase but I guess the issue might be the SHA1 is debug SHA1 and it might not be working with the release version of my app. What needs to be done ?

Comment: Stack Overflow does not work on any sense of urgency.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out - and if it can be helpful to you or future viewers...you need to add Google's SHA1 and SHA256(optional) keys into your firebase project. And it works just like how I wanted...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened with me, I reconfigured Firebase with Flutter and also added my payment details in firebase

I would suggest that you do the same and update the application.